# How do i take the 12th value in a SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large SQL database that I am pulling data to a web page. Instead of pulling every value, I want to take every 12th value. Is there a way to modify my current select statement?

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], 
        CASE When DataValue = '-9999' Then null
            When DataValue < '-60' Then null
            Else DataValue
            End DataValue, VariableID
        FROM DataValues
        WHERE SiteID = @siteID and VariableID IN(9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
        ) TableDate
    PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])) PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

END

This works except the data is staggered from one column to the next. I am not sure why all the data points don't start at the same location.

See the screen shot below.

=
[image]

Comment: Is this for MS SQL Server? Please add the tag of the database you're using, as solutions vary between databases.

Comment: Also, 12th as ordered by what criteria (if any)?

Comment: Why are you storing (or comparing) numbers as strings? If `DataValue` is a number you should compare it to a number. `'-999'` is a string value not a number

Comment: -9999 is an out of bounds value for the data I am storing. I just want to replace -9999 with null value to keep from that value being displayed on my highcharts graph.

Answer (score 1):

Using this theory (SQL Server) -

```
    with rNum As(
    SELECT  t.*,RowNum = row_number() over (order by date)
     FROM testdb.dbo.testtable t
     )
     select * from rNum where (RowNum % 12) = 0
```

Something like this -

```
with dVal As(
Select RowNum = row_number() over (order by datetime),DataValues.*
from datavalues)

SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT CAST(DateTimeUTC as SmallDateTime) as [DateTime], 
        CASE When DataValue = '-9999' Then null
            When DataValue < '-60' Then null
            Else DataValue
            End DataValue, VariableID
        FROM dVal
        WHERE 
        /* divide by 12 has no remainder */
        (RowNum % 12) = 0 and

        SiteID = @siteID and VariableID IN(9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
        ) TableDate
    PIVOT (SUM(DataValue) FOR VariableID IN ([9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])) PivotTable ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

Answer (score 1):

or,

```
Select * from DataValues d
where (Select count(*) from datavalues
      where DateTimeUTC < d.DateTimeUTC) % 12 = 0
```

to start at the 12th row, instead of the first row,

```
Select * from DataValues d
where (Select count(*) from datavalues
      where DateTimeUTC <= d.DateTimeUTC) % 12 = 0
```

or

```
Select * from DataValues d
where (Select count(*) from datavalues
      where DateTimeUTC < d.DateTimeUTC) % 12 = 11
```

Comment: This is pretty slick too.. but this actually starts at "Row Number" 1.. so it will actually be row numbers 1, 13, 25, etc...

Comment: This is old technique we used to have to use to rank or generate row numbers before there was `Rank`

Comment: Old technique? That's how you run row counts in MS Access, SQLite, MySQL that don't have window functions!